# connect iOS app to cloud database

Tags: ios, database, swift, cloud

I am creating an iOS app using Swift and I need to connect to an online SQL database to fetch and save data.

The app runs on user's phone locally but fetches only numbers from the cloud database.

Since I am new to iOS development I am looking for some good tutorials or guidance in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't so much about databases -- since the database is hosted in the cloud.  Instead you should focus your efforts on how to make network requests, and parse data like JSON using Swift.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

Comment: Thanks. The link that you posted talks about parsing a JSON data file. For me, the thing is I have my database set up at MongoLab and I need to access the database over there through the iOS app.